# ¿Cómo añadir un h2 centrado al comienzo de este section sin que me lo tome como un elemento inline?

Tags: html, css

Básicamente lo que intento hacer es colocar este h2: `<h2> Entrenamientos online intensivos, prácticos y de corta duración. </h2>` como un título centrado al comienzo del section pero cuando lo coloco se posiciona a la izquierda o me rompe las cards de abajo y lo toma como columna en lugar de fila que es lo que quiero.
Les dejo el detalle de mi código html y css donde si bien no aparece el h2 quisiera saber dónde debería colocarlo.

```css
 /*-----------------Cards cursos------------*/

.cardCursos{
background-image: url(../img/bckcursos.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50%;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
}

.fnd{
background-color: #4489a8;
z-index: 0;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
opacity: .75;
height: 100vh;
left: 0;
}

.cardForma{
height: 100vh;
padding: 0 4em;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
z-index: 10;
}

.undiv{
perspective: 1000px;
height: 28vh;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 10px;
}

.cardFront{
transform-style: preserve-3d;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.front,.cardBack{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 0.4em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front{
background: #ffffff;
}

.front img{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
}

.cardBack{
background-color: #2e2b3f;
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.front h3{
color: #2e2b3f;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}

.contentC{
transform: translateZ(60px);
}

.contentC h3{
margin-top: 1em;
}

.contentC p{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 2em;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
padding: 0 3em;
}

.undiv:hover .cardFront{
transform: rotateX(180deg);

}
/*-----------------Fin de Cursos------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.cardCursos{
    padding: 0 1em;
}

.undiv{
    flex-basis: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

}

@media (max-width: 1440px){ 
.cardForma{
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
}
```

```html
        <section>
            <div class="cardCursos">
                <div class="fnd"></div>
                    <div class="cardForma">
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/1.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>100% remoto</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Podés acceder a la plataforma desde tu compu o celular desde donde te
                                            encuentres.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/2.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>Desarrollo de habilidades</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Buscamos simular los espacios de trabajo lo más real posible.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/3.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>Entrenamiento por cohorte</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Grupos limitados con espacios de intercambio.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/4.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>Comunidad de pares</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Forma parte de una comunidad compuesta por mentores, profesionales y
                                            compañeros.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si esque antes quieres poner un h2 o si los h3 que tienes en los cards quieres centrarlos.

Igualmente te dejo una demo aqui, tanto en los h3 como implementando un h2

`````html
 <h2 style="text-align:center">Holiii</h2>
 <section>
                <div class="cardCursos">
                    <div class="fnd"></div>
                        <div class="cardForma">
                            <div class="undiv">
                                <div class="cardFront">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <img src="../img/1.png" alt="">
                                            <h3 style="text-align:center">100% remoto</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardBack">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <p>Podés acceder a la plataforma desde tu compu o celular desde donde te
                                                encuentres.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="undiv">
                                <div class="cardFront">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <img src="../img/2.png" alt="">
                                            <h3>Desarrollo de habilidades</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardBack">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <p>Buscamos simular los espacios de trabajo lo más real posible.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="undiv">
                                <div class="cardFront">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <img src="../img/3.png" alt="">
                                            <h3>Entrenamiento por cohorte</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardBack">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <p>Grupos limitados con espacios de intercambio.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="undiv">
                                <div class="cardFront">
                                    <div class="front">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <img src="../img/4.png" alt="">
                                            <h3>Comunidad de pares</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardBack">
                                        <div class="contentC">
                                            <p>Forma parte de una comunidad compuesta por mentores, profesionales y
                                                compañeros.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </section>````
`````

````
<!-- language: lang-css -->

 /*-----------------Cards cursos------------*/

.cardCursos{
    background-image: url(../img/bckcursos.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.fnd{
    background-color: #4489a8;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .75;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
}

.cardForma{
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0 4em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

.undiv{
    perspective: 1000px;
    height: 28vh;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
}

.cardFront{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.front,.cardBack{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front{
    background: #ffffff;
}

.front img{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.cardBack{
    background-color: #2e2b3f;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.front h3{
    color: #2e2b3f;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}

.contentC{
    transform: translateZ(60px);
}

.contentC h3{
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.contentC p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    padding: 0 3em;
}

.undiv:hover .cardFront{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);

}
/*-----------------Fin de Cursos------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .cardCursos{
        padding: 0 1em;
    }

    .undiv{
        flex-basis: 0 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 1440px){ 
.cardForma{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas poner el encabezado dentro de la sección, pero antes del contenedor flexible y crear la regla CSS para centrar:

```css
/*-----------------Cards cursos------------*/

.cardCursos{
background-image: url(../img/bckcursos.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50%;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
}

/* Configurar encabezado */
.cardCursos h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.fnd{
background-color: #4489a8;
z-index: 0;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
opacity: .75;
height: 100vh;
left: 0;
}

.cardForma{
height: 100vh;
padding: 0 4em;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
z-index: 10;
}

.undiv{
perspective: 1000px;
height: 28vh;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 10px;
}

.cardFront{
transform-style: preserve-3d;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.front,.cardBack{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 0.4em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front{
background: #ffffff;
}

.front img{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
}

.cardBack{
background-color: #2e2b3f;
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.front h3{
color: #2e2b3f;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}

.contentC{
transform: translateZ(60px);
}

.contentC h3{
margin-top: 1em;
}

.contentC p{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 2em;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
padding: 0 3em;
}

.undiv:hover .cardFront{
transform: rotateX(180deg);

}
/*-----------------Fin de Cursos------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.cardCursos{
    padding: 0 1em;
}

.undiv{
    flex-basis: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

}

@media (max-width: 1440px){ 
.cardForma{
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="cardCursos">
                <div class="fnd"></div>
                <!-- Poner encabezado fuera del contenedor flexible -->
                <h2>Entrenamientos online intensivos, prácticos y de corta duración.</h2>
                    <div class="cardForma">
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/1.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>100% remoto</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Podés acceder a la plataforma desde tu compu o celular desde donde te
                                            encuentres.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/2.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>Desarrollo de habilidades</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Buscamos simular los espacios de trabajo lo más real posible.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/3.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>Entrenamiento por cohorte</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Grupos limitados con espacios de intercambio.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="undiv">
                            <div class="cardFront">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <img src="../img/4.png" alt="">
                                        <h3>Comunidad de pares</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardBack">
                                    <div class="contentC">
                                        <p>Forma parte de una comunidad compuesta por mentores, profesionales y
                                            compañeros.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
```